# EXCEL sumproduct formula not counting correctly

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a formula in EXCEL 2013 that counts values where the decimal point = .16

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--(MOD(D2:D9,1)=0.16))
```

so for example 2.16, 15.16  will be a count of 2. However if the value is 32.16 or greater then will not count. This is very weird issue and cannot fathom this out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've hit a floating point error¹. The remainder reads as `0.159999999999997`, not `0.16`. Round it to at least four decimals to get an accurate read.

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--(ROUND(MOD(D2:D9,1), 4)=0.16))
```

---

¹ <sub>See [15 digit precision floating point errors](http://blogs.office.com/2008/04/10/understanding-floating-point-precision-aka-why-does-excel-give-me-seemingly-wrong-answers/) and [Floating-point arithmetic may give inaccurate results in Excel](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/78113).</sub>